# combine output of multiple functions into a pd.Series in python (like c() in R)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've been using `R` for data analysis and am trying to learn `python`. In R, I can create vectors with `c()`, which gives me back a "column" resulting from whatever I pass it. I often use it to concatenate sequences or repeated values. Something like this:

```
> test <- c(rep(1:2, each = 2), seq(5, 10, by = 2), runif(3))
> test
 [1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 2.0000000 2.0000000 5.0000000 7.0000000 9.0000000
 [8] 0.9237168 0.5051230 0.2367923
```

What is the pythonic way to do this (guessing with `pandas` or `numpy`)?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443778/python-equivalent-of-r-c-function) is the closest I've found, but it's only putting together `range()` objects. Trying to do the above in `python`, storing the output as a `pd.Series`, I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = pd.Series([np.repeat([1, 2], 2), 
                  np.arange(5, 10, 2),
                  np.random.random_sample(3)])
```

That gets me a sort of nested thing:

```
0                                        [1, 1, 2, 2]
1                                           [5, 7, 9]
2    [0.989736164378, 0.558979301843, 0.385354683044]
dtype: object
```

I see that I could [flatten the list manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) but that seems like overkill. I magically googled onto [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898159/python-pandas-series-combine-the-rows) which contained the potentially helpful `tolist()` function which I hadn't heard of. While that's about getting some row of dataframes (??) into a `pd.Series`, the function seems like it might do the trick?

Combining that I can use `+` to add lists (gleaned from the first linked question), and the `tolist()` bit from the last one, I found this:

```
test1 = np.repeat([1, 2], 2).tolist()
test2 = np.arange(5, 10, 2).tolist()
test3 = np.random.random_sample(3).tolist()

test = pd.Series(test1 + test2 + test3)

0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    2.000000
3    2.000000
4    5.000000
5    7.000000
6    9.000000
7    0.472650
8    0.077398
9    0.672734
dtype: float64
```

Hopefully what I'm trying to do is clear. I like that with `c()`, you pass in whatever you want and can elegantly string together a series of generated numbers in a desired pattern. I was surprised by how tough it was to do this with a `pd.Series` and infer from that I'm doing it wrong!

How is this typically done with `python`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start with numpy arrays, you can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
pd.np.concatenate([np.repeat([1, 2], 2), np.arange(5, 10, 2), np.random.random_sample(3)])
#array([ 1.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ,  2.        ,  5.        ,
#        7.        ,  9.        ,  0.61116272,  0.48863116,  0.84436643])
```

---

If you start with `pandas.Series` objects, you can [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.append.html) one series to another:

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.repeat([1, 2], 2))
s2 = pd.Series(np.arange(5, 10, 2))
s3 = pd.Series(np.random.random_sample(3))
​    
s1.append([s2, s3], ignore_index=True)
#0    1.000000
#1    1.000000
#2    2.000000
#3    2.000000
#4    5.000000
#5    7.000000
#6    9.000000
#7    0.766968
#8    0.730897
#9    0.196995
#dtype: float64
```

or use `pd.concat` method:

```
pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Not quite as short as I'd have hoped, but this is helpful. Did you mean to have `pd.np.concatenate(...)`? I wondered if you might have meant `pd.Series(np.concatenate(...))`?

Comment: Sure this can't beat `c()` :). If you want a *Series* object as result, then you need wrap `pd.Series` as `pd.Series(np.concatenate(...))`. `pd.np.concatenate` is also a valid syntax, which avoids you from importing `numpy` again if you have already imported `pandas`.

Comment: Good to know. I likely don't really know if I need a series or not as I'm so new. I was feeding this back into a `pd.DataFrame` as a new column, so I'm assuming so. In either case, this was great to work through!